# Is Stripe.js supposed to catch ALL errors that may occur?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Users can subscribe to my Rails app through [Stripe](https://stripe.com):

```
class Subscription::CreditCardController < Subscription::PaymentController

  def new
    stripe_customer = Customers::FindOrCreate.call(current_account)
    if stripe_customer
      @stripe_subscription = Subscriptions::Create.call(current_account, @price, :payment_behavior => "default_incomplete")
      @client_secret = @stripe_subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
    else
      flash[:notice] = "An error occurred."
      redirect_to plans_path
    end
  end

  def create
    flash[:success] = "Subscription created."
    redirect_to plans_path
  end

end
```

I am relying on Stripe.js to catch any errors that may occur:

```
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handlePayment();
  });

  function handlePayment() {
    stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret.value, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card,
        billing_details: {
          name: name.value,
          email: email.value
        }
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        displayError(result.error);
      } else {
        form.submit();
      }
    });
  }
```

This works in 99 % of all test cases so far. Stripe.js catches pretty much [every error that can possibly occur](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses). But on some rare occasions it **does NOT**, so that the error occurs on the server when Stripe is trying to create the Subscription, leaving it in an `incomplete` state.

This is a major problem because I am not handling these type of errors in my `create` controller action right now.

So why is it that Stripe catches *most* of these errors but not *all*? As a developer, am I supposed to validate user input with Stripe.js **AND** on the server? Or will one of the two suffice? Reading through Stripe's documentation I was under the impression that Stripe.js will handle everything for me and that I won't have to add additional checks on the server level.

Is this not correct?

Comment: Well, stripe.js can only handle the errors that get raised during confirmCardPayment, but your backend call to `Subscriptions::Create.call` could fail for myriad other reasons before that, like a transient network problem connecting to Stripe's API, or your hosting provider cutting off your server's external network access, or an outage on Stripe's side, or many many other things. So you do need at least a try/catch block to present some kind of defined error path to the user. I'm actually curious what the rare errors you see are exactly, that might help clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @karllekko. I do not remember exactly which errors I saw, but I think a `card_declined` error was among them, and possibly a `requires_payment_method` as well. I am not exactly sure as these errors are very rare and therefore hard to reproduce.